# How to select index over two dimension in PyTorch?

Tags: numpy, pytorch

Given `a = torch.randn(3, 2, 4, 5)`, how I can select sub tensor like  `(2, :, 0, :), (1, :, 1, :), (2, :, 2, :), (0, :, 3, :)` (a resulting tensor of size `(2, 4, 5)` or `(4, 2, 5)`?

While `a[2, :, 0, :]` gives

```
 0.5580 -0.0337  1.0048 -0.5044  0.6784
-1.6117  1.0084  1.1886  0.1278  0.3739
[torch.FloatTensor of size 2x5]
```

however, `a[[2, 1, 2, 0], :, [0, 1, 2, 3], :]` gives

> TypeError: Performing basic indexing on a tensor and encountered an error indexing dim 0 with an object of type list. The only supported types are integers, slices, numpy scalars, or if indexing with a torch.LongTensor or torch.ByteTensor only a single Tensor may be passed.

though `numpy` returns a `(4, 2, 5)` tensor successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work for you?

```
import torch

a = torch.randn(3, 2, 4, 5)
print(a.size())

b = [a[2, :, 0, :], a[1, :, 1, :], a[2, :, 2, :], a[0, :, 3, :]]
b = torch.stack(b, 0)

print(b.size()) # torch.Size([4, 2, 5])
```

Comment: I was thinking too much about this and this approach is neat. Torch notation of 4D array is way different that numpy's. +1. There are many issues https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/2412 .

Comment: Is that mean I must use a `for` list comprehension to build `b` generally?

Comment: @displayname not necessarily. you didn't mention your whole problem, you just mentioned a specific problem and considering list is one way to solve the problem.

Comment: The indices is actually generated by some context, so I think in real problem, a `for` is needed. Thank you.